# Change Fody weavers.xml Location

Tags: c#, winforms, nuget, fody, fody-costura

VisualStudio 2017, latest Fody nuget package, WinForms, C#

When you install https://github.com/Fody/Fody it autogenerates `FodyWeavers.xml` in the project main directory.

How can I change the location for this file?

I tried changing content include in project settings `<Content Include="Properties\FodyWeavers.xml" />` and in Fody.targets    `<ProjectWeaverXml>$(ProjectDir)\Properties\FodyWeavers.xml</ProjectWeaverXml>`.

However when compiling I still get the following error:

> Error     Fody: Could not find path to weavers file. Searched
>   'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\projects\FodyWeavers.xml',
>   'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\projects\fodytest\FodyWeavers.xml'.

Comment: @rene I mentioned that I already tried that in my question. Thanks tho.

Comment: @rene I mention Fody.target in the same sentence.

Comment: Can you please the fody weaver xml to the root folder?
Could you please verify the xml structure also?
<Weavers>
 <list of fody plugins>
</Weavers>

Comment: @Jenny did you ever find a solution to this?